# Click don't work well when i scroll, jScrollPane and ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-jscrollpane

I will be much clearer the problem is that I load a table via ajax (jquery) whose cells can contain links, buttons or dropdwons and now if I click on an item when the table is loaded if I click on a link which is in a cell that pops up everything works fine but when I scroll to see the other items the links don't work directly and takes you to the start of the scroll you have to click multiple times for it to work.

```
function siteScrollPage() {
$('.scroll-user-table').jScrollPane({
   showArrows: true,
  hijackInternalLinks: true,
  autoReinitialise: true,
  horizontalArrowPositions: 'after',
});


  $.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {loaded: 'loaded'},
  })
  .done(function(response) {
    firstLoaded = false;
    $('#add-loaded-invoice').html(response[1]['invoice']);
    $('#edit-category-modal').html(response[1]['edit']);
    $('#edit-invoice-client-modal').html(response[1]['client']);
    $('#edit-invoice-marchant-modal').html(response[1]['marchant']);
    $('#edit-invoice-cancel-modal').html(response[1]['cancel']);
  })
  .fail(function(response) {
  })
  .always(function(response) {
    siteEditCategoryModal();
    siteEditCostsLivraison();
    sitesStatusInvoiceLivraison();
    siteEditStatusInvoiceLivraison();
    siteEditInvoiceLivraisonClient();
    siteEditInvoiceLivraisonmarchant();
    siteFirstTimeLoadedInvoiceLivraison();
    siteEditInvoiceLivraisonClientClose();
    siteEditInvoiceLivraisonmarchantClose();
    siteCancelInvoiceLivraisonmarchant();
    siteNoCancelInvoiceLivraisonmarchant();
    siteScrollPage();
    loader.addClass('hidden');
  });
}
```